# Google Translator Toolkit API Error ("Multipart must have Atom and media part")

Tags: php, api, gdata-api

I try upload document (srt subtitles) to Google Translator Toolkit via API.
But I get an error: "Multipart must have Atom and media part". What's wrong?

**My request:**

```
POST /toolkit/feeds/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: translate.google.com
GData-Version: 1.0
Authorization: GoogleLogin Auth=[myauth]
Content-Length: 404
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Slug: test.srt
--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gtt="http://schemas.google.com/gtt/2009/11"> 
  <title>test</title> 
  <gtt:sourceLanguage>en</gtt:sourceLanguage> 
  <gtt:targetLanguage>ru</gtt:targetLanguage> 
</entry> 
--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Content-Type: application/x-subrip

data
--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU--
```

**Answer:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 18:20:24 GMT
Expires: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 18:20:24 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

27
Multipart must have Atom and media part
0
```

[Link to Google Translator Toolkit Data API Reference Guide v1.0](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/gtt/docs/1.0/reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4) states that there should be an empty line separating the headers and the body.

> Request (section 5) and Response (section 6) messages use the generic message format of RFC 822 [9] for transferring entities (the payload of the message). Both types of message consist of a start-line, zero or more header fields (also known as "headers"), an empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the header fields, and possibly a message-body.

Your request should look like this:

```
POST /toolkit/feeds/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: translate.google.com
GData-Version: 1.0
Authorization: GoogleLogin Auth=[myauth]
Content-Length: 404
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Slug: test.srt

--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gtt="http://schemas.google.com/gtt/2009/11"> 
  <title>test</title> 
  <gtt:sourceLanguage>en</gtt:sourceLanguage> 
  <gtt:targetLanguage>ru</gtt:targetLanguage> 
</entry> 
--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU
Content-Type: application/x-subrip

data
--SKYqYanmBJWCtDU--
```