# Google Apps Email Migration API error "must have atom and media part"

Tags: xml

I have already viewed this question/answer which is similar to mine:

[Google Translator Toolkit API Error ("Multipart must have Atom and media part")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069872/google-translator-toolkit-api-error-multipart-must-have-atom-and-media-part)

However the suggested solution is not relevant to me.  I am attempting to use the Google Email Migration API and POST a message to a users inbox.  I have successfully authenticated.  The response to the POST is http error 400 bad request, and the html error is "must have atom and media part". Below is the http headers and data that I am sending.  I assume Google is having some problem parsing out the different parts, but I cannot see what I might be doing wrong.

http headers:

```
Content-Length: 1235
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=Part_0_25934938.1266495790627
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAPUAAAB7vtNS...
```

http data (note: begins with CR/LF):

```
--Part_0_25934938.1266495790627
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<?xml version="1.0"; encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"  term="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006#mailItem"/>
  <atom:content xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" type="message/rfc822"/>
  <apps:mailItemProperty value="IS_INBOX"/>
</entry>

--Part_0_25934938.1266495790627
Content-Type: message/rfc822

MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.216.170.147 with HTTP; Fri, 26 Mar 2010 12:54:28 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sat, 27 Mar 2010 03:54:28 +0800
Delivered-To: darcy@example.com
Message-ID: <203b3a4f1043461254v14855b71w9ce59e3abcf45962@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: hello multipart
From: Elizabeth Bennet <bennet@example.com>
To: Fitzwilliam Darcy <darcy@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=000e0cdf7740f8017e0482b9877a

--000e0cdf7740f8017e0482b9877a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

howdy multipart!

--000e0cdf7740f8017e0482b9877a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

howdy multipart!

--000e0cdf7740f8017e0482b9877a--

--Part_0_25934938.1266495790627--
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to invalid Content-Length i.e. it being less that what it should be and the server is unable to parse the parts of the message.

Comment: I'll take another look at it, but I don't think that is the issue - I create the post data by writing everything to a file, then I re-open the file and get its length, and use that for content-length.